# Open URL through the same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to use a iframe tag for opening google but it seems to be impossible. So I want to try an other tricks. I want to split my window browser into two windows so when people click on a URL link on the left window (the main page) it opens the google page assimilated in the other window. So if I click a second time in an other button, the link is open in the page of the right. It's kind of controlling always the same page/window.

Comment: That sounds interesting, although not sure how you'd render it for responsiveness, but more importantly... what have you tried already.. you have provided no code.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this ? or nicely said what is the behavior you want to accomplish ?

Comment: You cannot access window object of cross domain page so this is obviously not possible to set it on same window.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set an id to right side iframe and for each link in the left side set the target to the iframe id.

```
<a href="www.google.com.br" target="content"/>
<iframe id="content"></iframe>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all, can you provide an example? Here's what I tried to test - https://jsfiddle.net/leecollingsco/0o69fb6r/